# Suitable driver for BLDC motor

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, connecting

I have a BLDC motor with Hall connections Hu, Hv, Hw and U, V, W. I am looking at a driver for the BLDC motor, but the driver has hall connections HA, HB and HC. Are Hu, Hv, Hw and HA, HB, and HC the same? Can I use this driver to run my BLDC motor?

Comment: Yes, they are the same.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes both are same you can go ahead with this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).